# Forma correta de pegar valores de "Sub Array's" JSON no PHP

Tags: php, json

Fiz o seguinte código:

```
<?php

//dados de um arquivo JSON
$json_str = '[ {
  "documentoId" : 1057615,
  "nome" : "1542980818602.pdf",
  "assunto" : "AQUI FICA O ASSUNTO DO DOCUMENTO",
  "dataEnvio" : "23/11/2018 10:46:58",
  "tipoDocumento" : {
    "tipoDocumentoId" : 137,
    "nome" : "Nome de um Tipo"
  },
  "link" : null
}, {
  "documentoId" : 1057748,
  "nome" : "1542983033040.pdf",
  "assunto" : "FICA AQUI OUTRO ASSUNTO",
  "dataEnvio" : "23/11/2018 11:23:53",
  "tipoDocumento" : {
    "tipoDocumentoId" : 105,
    "nome" : "Nome de Outro Tipo"
  },
  "link" : null
}, {
  "documentoId" : 1064570,
  "nome" : "1543494201384.pdf",
  "assunto" : "ESCREVO AQUI MAIS OUTRO ASSUNTO",
  "dataEnvio" : "29/11/2018 09:23:21",
  "tipoDocumento" : {
    "tipoDocumentoId" : 135,
    "nome" : "Outro Tipo Aqui"
  },
  "link" : null
}, {
  "documentoId" : 1064592,
  "nome" : "1543494685352.pdf",
  "assunto" : "OUTRO ASSUNTO ESCRITO AQUI ",
  "dataEnvio" : "29/11/2018 09:31:25",
  "tipoDocumento" : {
    "tipoDocumentoId" : 134,
    "nome" : "Mais Um Tipo"
  },
  "link" : null
} ]';

//faz o parsing na string, gerando um objeto PHP
$jsonObj = json_decode($json_str);

//navega pelos elementos do array, imprimindo os objetos
foreach ( $jsonObj as $e )
    {

        if (property_exists($e, "tipoDocumento")) { 
        $deps = $e->tipoDocumento;
        foreach ( $deps as $d );
        echo "<div>Tipo de Documento: $d - Descrição: $e->assunto - Data de envio: $e->dataEnvio - Nome: $e->nome </div>";
    }
    }
?>
```

Eu gostaria de pegar o valor de `tipoDocumento` > `nome`. O código retorna:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está funcionando perfeitamente.

Porém acredito que não seja a solução correta de "filtrar" esses valores, pois não há algo que está definindo que eu queira pegar o valor de `tipoDocumento` > `nome` e mesmo assim está sendo perfeitamente.

Observem que o mesmo objeto `tipoDocumento` possui dentro dele `tipoDocumentoId` e `nome`, e mesmo assim está ignorando e sendo imprimido o valor de `tipoDocumento` > `nome` perfeitamente.

```
"tipoDocumento" : {
        "tipoDocumentoId" : 137,
        "nome" : "Nome de um Tipo"
      },
```

Qual a forma correta de pegar esses valores?

E se ao invés de `tipoDocumento` > `nome` eu quisesse `tipoDocumento` > `tipoDocumentoId`, como iria setar isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está neste `foreach`:

```
foreach ( $deps as $d );
```

Repare no ponto-e-vírgula no final. Isto significa que este `foreach` está "vazio" (ou seja, ele itera por `$deps` mas não faz nada em cada iteração).

---

Ao fazer `$deps = $e->tipoDocumento;`, a variável `$deps` tem um objeto como este:

```
"tipoDocumento" : {
  "tipoDocumentoId" : 137,
  "nome" : "Nome de um Tipo"
},
```

Então você faz um `foreach` nele, mas sem fazer nada dentro deste `foreach`. Ou seja, na primeira iteração, a varivável `$d` contém o valor `137`, mas nada é feito com ele (lembre-se, por causa do ponto-e-vírgula, o corpo do `foreach` está vazio). Depois, na segunda iteração, a variável `$d` contém o valor `"Nome de um Tipo"`, mas nada é feito com ele também.

Após o término do `foreach`, a variável `$d` terá o valor do último elemento percorrido (no caso, o valor da chave "nome"). Por isso o `echo` logo em seguida imprime o valor desta chave e tudo "parece funcionar".

Este comportamento (da variável continuar com o valor do último elemento do array após o término do `foreach`) é descrito na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> *Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop*

---

Se você não quer percorrer todos os valores de determinado objeto e só quer alguns valores específicos, não use `foreach`. Basta acessar cada valor diretamente. Por exemplo, se quiser somente o `tipoDocumentoId`:

```
foreach ( $jsonObj as $e ) {
    if (property_exists($e, "tipoDocumento")) {
        $deps = $e->tipoDocumento;
        echo "<div>Tipo de Documento ID: $deps->tipoDocumentoId - Descrição: $e->assunto - Data de envio: $e->dataEnvio - Nome: $e->nome </div>";
    }
}
```

Saída:

```
<div>Tipo de Documento ID: 137 - Descrição: AQUI FICA O ASSUNTO DO DOCUMENTO - Data de envio: 23/11/2018 10:46:58 - Nome: 1542980818602.pdf </div>
<div>Tipo de Documento ID: 105 - Descrição: FICA AQUI OUTRO ASSUNTO - Data de envio: 23/11/2018 11:23:53 - Nome: 1542983033040.pdf </div>
<div>Tipo de Documento ID: 135 - Descrição: ESCREVO AQUI MAIS OUTRO ASSUNTO - Data de envio: 29/11/2018 09:23:21 - Nome: 1543494201384.pdf </div>
<div>Tipo de Documento ID: 134 - Descrição: OUTRO ASSUNTO ESCRITO AQUI  - Data de envio: 29/11/2018 09:31:25 - Nome: 1543494685352.pdf </div>
```

Repare que removi o `foreach` e ao imprimir eu usei `$deps->tipoDocumentoId`, que pega o valor da chave `"tipoDocumentoId"`. Se quiser pegar o valor da chave `"nome"`, use `$deps->nome`.

Comment: Muito interessante! =)